# Remove MySettings entry

Tags: 2013, permissions, my-site, editing-menu

I am using SP2013 I would like to remove the **My Settings** entry in the menu.

[image: My Settings]

I removed the Personal Permission on the Read role of Visitors group, but no luck.

[image: Permission]

I have to disable it for all sites. (so I won't use CSS)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a no-code solution ? If you are OK with using JQuery or CSS and

If you are **Using custom master page**, you can refer the CSS in the master page so that the link is hidden on all the sites.

If you are using the **default sharepoint master page** you can use a delegate control to inject Jquery/CSS without modifying the master page.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569897/UsingplusDelegateplusControlplusinplusSharepoint) is a link to get information on delegate control.

Answer (score 1):

I have done several solutions to this. It's simple ...

Just open the SharePoint Designer, open your SharePoint, go to "All Files", after that click "_catalogs" then "masterpage" and open the "seattle.master" in Advanced Editing.

Go to more or less line 90, will contain a div with the id "suiteBarRight". Within this div contains all the menus of the "Settings".

Look up to find the menu with the id="MenuItem_Settings".

[image]

If you see this menu, it contains a tag called "PermissionsString", I recommend you leave at least a full control permissions of webApplication.